# QR code is generated by using 'Simple QrCode' package not showing correctly?

Tags: laravel-8, qr-code, laravel-7, generated-code, laravel-package

I have used 'Simple QrCode' package to generate 'QR Code'. Followed the instruction https://www.positronx.io/how-to-generate-various-qr-codes-in-laravel-application/

I want to generate Logo Inside QR CODE,

**Code**

`{!! QrCode::format('png')->merge('https://hellovcard.com/profile.png', .3, true)->generate('RemoteStack'); !!}`

**QR code**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYqa9.png)

Where I went wrong? Why qr code it is showing like the above mentioned image?